# MIPS - syscall prints the wrong asciiz

Tags: assembly, mips

I am writing a program that reads 4 integers to an array from the user in an ascending order. If the values are not ascending the program prints an error message ("bigger" label in .data) and reads another integer from the user.
After reading the integers, I iterate and print them with comma after each integer.

When I call the comma print, I get a space + the value of the "bigger" label (the error message) instead of comma.
Code:

```
.data
array:  .byte   4
comma:  .asciiz ",\n"
bigger: .asciiz "The array inputs should be in an ascending order!\n"

.text
main:   # main program entry    
la $a0, array       # load array address
jal get_array       # call get_array procedure with the array address
addi $t0, $zero, 0  # set loop counter to 0
la   $t1, array     # load array address
loop: beq $t0, 4, endLoop # for $t0 < 4
      li $v0, 1     # v0 integer syscall
      lb $a0, 0($t1)    # load current byte of the array    
      syscall       # print it
      la $a0, comma # load address of comma string
      li $v0, 4     # v0 string syscall    
      syscall       # print comma
      addi $t1, $t1, 1  # array address pointer++
      addi $t0, $t0, 1  # loop counter++
      j loop        # loop
endLoop:
      li $v0, 10    # exit program
      syscall

get_array:          # read asceding integer array from the user
    addi $t0, $zero, 1  # inserts count
    la   $t1, ($a0)     # array address pointer
    addi $v0, $zero, 5  # read integer syscall
    syscall         # read integer from the user
    sb   $v0, 0($t1)    # save integer in current array address pointer
    addi $t1, $t1, 1    # array address pointer++
loop1:  beq  $t0, 4, endLoop1   # for $t0 < 4
    addi $v0, $zero, 5  # read integer syscall
    syscall         # read integer from the user
    lb   $t2, -1($t1)   # read the previous array value
    slt  $t3, $t2, $v0  # check if current value is bigger than previous value
    beq  $t3, 0, invalid    # if not go to invalid
valid:  sb   $v0, 0($t1)    # valid - save new value in current array address pointer
    addi $t1, $t1, 1    # array address pointer++
    addi $t0, $t0, 1    # inserts count++
    j    loop1      # loop
invalid:            # invalid - new value doesnt keep array ascending
    addi $v0, $zero, 4  # print string syscall 
    la $a0, bigger      # print error message
    syscall         # print error message       
    j    loop1      # loop
endLoop1:
    jr $ra          # return to caller
```

Example:
for the input:

```
1
2
3
4
```

The print is:

```
1  The array inputs should be in an ascending order!
2  The array inputs should be in an ascending order!
3  The array inputs should be in an ascending order!
4  The array inputs should be in an ascending order!
```

Expected result:

```
1,
2,
3,
4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array:  .byte   4` doesn't reserve space for 4 bytes; it reserves space for a single byte with an initial value of 4.

What you want is `.space`, i.e:  `array: .space 4`

---

What ends up happening now is that the last 3 of your inputs overwrite the `comma` string, including its NUL terminator.